# How to correct Search Code with Inner join?

Tags: sql

Help pls...How to correct this code?

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.CatName, " +
       "Products.Description, Products.Price FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON " +
       "Products.CatID = Categories.CatID ORDER BY Products.Price DESC WHERE " + column + " LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
```

Comment: The starting quote (i.e. double) should start at the `SELECT`?

Comment: There should be single quote in case of SQL

Comment: read up on SQL injection

Comment: Hope little Bobby Tables would not pay a visit to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order by` should after `where` clause

```
"SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.CatName, " +
"Products.Description, Products.Price FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON " +
"Products.CatID = Categories.CatID " +
"WHERE " + column + " LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
"ORDER BY Products.Price DESC"
```

And as other comment said, you should consider use `SQLParameters` to avoid **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 0):

Anti injection SQL code you want?

As follows:

```
"SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.CatName, " +
"Products.Description, Products.Price FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON " +
"Products.CatID = Categories.CatID WHERE " + column + 
"LIKE CONCAT('%'," + keyword + ",'%')" +
"ORDER BY Products.Price DESC";
```